# Serve huge files directy from s3 bucket (in a s3 compatible cloud, not amazo) in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3

I have a huge file stored in a s3 compatible cloud ocean (not Amazon). I want to have a download button which will result to downloading this file for user.

I have installed "Media Cloud" plugin which has ability to connect to s3 compatible cloud. But I cant find a way to serve this file which is only saved in my s3 bucket in my wordpress.

Comment: This question is very broad and open ended right now, can you please tell us more about what you have already tried and where you have **specific** problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 1 file to serve, you should be able to get the URL of the file in your s3 bucket admin panel where the file lives.

The main thing you need to check if the object (the file) is publically readable and your bucket is set up as a "static website" so it can serve HTTP. If it's not, you won't be given an object URL to put on your site.

I'm not sure who you host your s3 with if you say it's not Amazon, but [here's a guide on how to do it if you did use Amazon](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/how-allow-public-access-amazon-bucket/).